# using data from database in html javascript

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, database, mongodb

I developed an Android app that save via http request some data in mongodb. everything is working fine and it's ok. Now it comes the second part of the project, to use this data in a html javascript, and I can't figure out how to do it.

This is from my `server.js` and it's the part where I get the data from database and I send it to `localhost:3000` in `res.send(data)`.

```
 app.get('/',(req,res)=> {

      MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true }, function(err,           
 db) {
        if (err) throw err;
        var dbo = db.db("mydb");
        dbo.collection("date_locatie").find({"imei" : imei_number},              
 function(err, result) {
          if (err) throw err;
          console.log(data.imei);
          res.send(data);
        });
    });
  });
```

Now I have made a html page called `mapa.html` and after I past data from mongo to node `(res.send(data))` I've tried to send the html page too with `res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/mapa.html'))` and it seems `express/node.js` not working like this. If I put the `res.sendFile` line after `res.send` I receive an error

> Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.

I understand I can't `res.sendFile` after I `res.send`, but I can't figure out how I can use the data from mongodb in that html page.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot pass variables to an html page. You must use a template engine. I recommend using EJS templates. You can install it by running `npm install ejs`, then inside your code specify the template engine that you are using by writing `app.set('view engine', 'ejs');`. The pages you create must have an extension `.ejs`. Now you can load the page using `render`, like this:

```
res.render('page name',{
      variables: someVariable
    });
```

And inside of your template print the passed variables with `<%= variables %>`
Hope my answer helps. If you have any questions feel free to ask.

Comment: isn't easier with a jquery?

Comment: jQuery is for front-end. You can't use it for back-end.

Comment: i save location from android, and i need to put a marker on google maps page, whitch is my html on that location. i can use EJS to render the google maps map?

Comment: You can write any html markup that you want inside the EJS template and also pass the location data to it.

Comment: and this res.render should be in the app.get where i connect to mongodb?

Comment: if i use res.render instead of res.send i need to use EJS?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198307/discussion-between-grigory-volkov-and-tudor-stanciulescu).